# Try Catch for OS Errors due to Syntax when compiling C++ Program in Python

Tags: python, c++, compiler-errors, operating-system

I am trying to create a python function which will execute a C++ script based off users input. The function replaces some lines in a C++ file, and then executes it on python. Whenever the lines being replaced in the C++ file have wrong syntax, an error on invalid syntax occurs. In such case, I want the function to return -1, rather than just crashing or getting confused about wrong syntax/input on behalf of the user.

I have tried:

- running a try catch statement in the python function
- running a try catch statement in the C++ code
- running a bash script with a try catch for compilation error

Nevertheless, none of these options has worked. Any takers?

[C++ segment as a string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSnIt.png)
[Python function implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yo3n.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using subprocess.check_output not just check call?

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output
It would seem that this will raise an exception if clang++ fails to execute properly, which would imply a build error.

Sorry, cannot comment too NOOb.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the return value of clang++ on invalid code compilation. If there is no way to tell by return value you may have to parse the output of clang++.

To check return value, in terminal (assuming bash):
clang++ valid_file.cpp

echo $?

clang++ invalid_file.cpp

echo $?